# Keycloak login form uses two subsequent http and https requests to authenticate

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

We've implemented use of Keycloak as authorization service on our project.

Upon Log In, after user credentials are filled in, the Keycloak log in form sends two subsequent requests and one of these is **http** that contains in response headers exactly the same link that uses secured protocol (**https**) and redirects to it. I cannot find any documentation information about possible configuration of this nor did find anything helpful in my admin pannel...

***Question***: Is there anything I can do to avoid this redundant http call/redirect?

*REQUEST 1:*

General:
http://{auth-root-url}/auth/realms/{realm-name}/login-actions/authenticate?session_code={session_code}&client_id={client_id}&tab_id={tab_id}

Request Method: POST
Status Code: 307 Internal Redirect

Response Headers:
https://{auth-root-url}/auth/realms/{realm-name}/login-actions/authenticate?session_code={the_same_session_code}&client_id={the_same_client_id}&tab_id={the_same_tab_id}
Non-Authoritative-Reason: HSTS

*REQUEST 2:*

https://{auth-root-url}/auth/realms/{realm-name}/login-actions/authenticate?session_code={the_same_session_code}&client_id={the_same_client_id}&tab_id={the_same_tab_id}

Request Method: POST
Status Code: 302

Comment: Could be a configuration thing on the Spring Boot side: does your config have the auth-root-url specified with `http` by any chance?

Comment: I double checked, all the configuration urls are also set with https...